# custom indeterminate progress drawable scaling

Tags: android, progress-bar, drawable, scale

Trying to use a custom indeterminate drawable that will use vertical scaling. It comes out looking strange, it seems as though the bottom row of pixels are the only ones scaled, so it comes out looking like this.

[image]

I want it to be vertically scaled so it looks like a traditional candy-stripe indeterminate progress bar. The reason I need it to be scalable is that the area it will be covering will be weighted, so I can't have a static size.

Setting the minimum height seems to change nothing. Changing the drawables to 9-patch screws up the tiling (it turns into one png covering the whole area instead of horizontally tiling. In the end, I need horizontal tiling, and vertical scaling.

Anyone have an idea for me?

EDIT:

Reading up, I see in ProgressBar, that they wrap all your bitmaps like so:

```
        final Bitmap tileBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        if (mSampleTile == null) {
            mSampleTile = tileBitmap;
        }

        final ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(getDrawableShape());

        final BitmapShader bitmapShader = new BitmapShader(tileBitmap,
                Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setShader(bitmapShader);

        return (clip) ? new ClipDrawable(shapeDrawable, Gravity.LEFT,
                ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL) : shapeDrawable;
```

In otherwords, the force your bitmap to tile with Clamp, instead of respecting your original tile setting. I am sure there is a reason for this that I don't know. The only think I can think of is to write my own progress bar class that does my own tiling.

Answer (score 0):

probably you should use pattern. see documentation [drawable-resourse](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap) please look to the 
"XML Bitmap" section of the document. there is a tileMode="repeat" i think this will solve you problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@[package:]drawable/drawable_resource"
    android:antialias=["true" | "false"]
    android:dither=["true" | "false"]
    android:filter=["true" | "false"]
    android:gravity=["top" | "bottom" | "left" | "right" | "center_vertical" |
                      "fill_vertical" | "center_horizontal" | "fill_horizontal" |
                      "center" | "fill" | "clip_vertical" | "clip_horizontal"]
    android:tileMode=["disabled" | "clamp" | "repeat" | "mirror"] />
```

Comment: just adding something, got around to trying this and it doesn't work. thanks for the suggestion though